# improving our answers to palaeography questions

Tags: discussion, answers

For the questions where people have difficulty reading documents, such as this recent request:

[Deciphering Work Profession from marriage certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18921/1006)

Can we do something to make the answers of more general interest instead of simply solving the riddle for the person whose document it is?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see something in the answers that would help the skillbuilding of people who have less experience at transcription.  If we write explicitly "the letter at the start of the mystery word is comparable to the S at the start of Smith in the officiant's name, so I think it is also an S" then anyone reading the answer later can see how the answerer arrived at their reading.

For answers where an occupation or disease is noted, we could give links to resources about the occupation or disease, and so on.

I realize that we often don't have the full document to work with, and people often post snippets, but if we encourage people to link to full document pages when possible, we can show how to use the entire document to decipher the bits we don't know.